# Codeigniter / PHP - declare class private var

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, private, var

hi i have this simple class for example:

```
class Asd{
 private $_url = $this->config->config['url']; 
}
```

but it doesn't get the config param any clue on how to do that?

How do i call a config param in `private var` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
class Asd {
   private $_url;
   public function __construct() {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $this->_url = $CI->config->config['url']; 
   } 
}
```

You can't declare class property as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be assigned only **constructor**!

```
class Asd{
 private $_url;
 public function __construct() {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $this->_url = $CI->config->config['url'];  
   }  
}
```

Below is not possible

```
 class Asd{
     private $_url='www.so.com';
     public function __construct() {
          $CI =& get_instance();
          $this->_url = $CI->config->config['url'];  
       }  
    }
```